# Azure Data factory, Data flow output to be uploaded to FTP

Tags: azure-data-factory

Below is my dataflow. My requirement is
1)To merge 2 files.
2)Create a merged tab file
3) Upload the file to FTP

[image]

I was able to achieve first 2 steps. Now gettibg error while trying to upload to FTP.Showing as FTP is not supported as sink Dataset.

Is there any way I can achieve this.

My ultimate aim is to upload this merged file to FTP.

Getting error as below while running the pipeline for above dataflow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FTP sink will not support Dataflow. As per [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp?tabs=data-factory#supported-capabilities),

[image]

You can raise the feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

**Or**

You can try this alternative approach with custom activity or use logic app FTP operations.

[image]

Comment: It will be very great if you can elaborate the answer.   I used DataFlow here as I have to merge 2 files.

Comment: Currently, dataflow not supported FTP. You can raise a feature request as mentioned above .

Comment: Can you access the server using SFTP intead of FTP? SFTP is supported as a Sink.

Comment: as @JoelCochran said, SFTP is the preferred method nowadays, and FTP is not used as often as before, hence FTP is not supported, SFTP has many advantages over FTP so consider that in your architecture.